# Ho to load css file only for a specific Vue Component?

Tags: vue.js

I have created a headless application with vue and now I need to load a css file exclusively for a specific component.
In the code below I have inserted the css file, but unfortunately it is displayed globally throughout the application.

```
<script>
export default {
name: "FriendComponent",
...
}
</script>

<style>
@import 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css';
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

To apply any CSS file or code to a specific component, you need to add `scoped` in your `style` tag of the component.

Have a look at this:

```
<style scoped>
@import 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css';
</style>
```

This will apply CSS to this specific component.

Comment: I have also tried inserting scoped, but the css file is read globally.

Comment: @user17368086 are you sure you haven't defined the same CSS file else where?